# How can I count number of iterations that ran for sparse linear solver in SciPy

Tags: python

I'm trying to use scipy.sparse.linalg.cg to solve linear system. I want to know how many iteration ran to achieve the specific tolerance?

Comment: I guess you're confident that there's a one-size-fits-all answer to this that doesn't require you to show us any code or give us any other details?  If you've got any doubt, then maybe you should show us a bit more of what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

scipy.sparse.linalg.cg takes a optional argument of callback, which evaluates at each iteration of the conjugate gradient algorithm and takes the current vector as an argument. By using a nonlocal variable reference you can extract the total number of iterations as follows

```
iters = 0

def nonlocal_iterate(arr):
    nonlocal iters
    iters+=1

x, info = scipy.sparse.linalg.cg(A, b, callback=nonlocal_iterate)
```

Answer (score 0):

So far, there is not way you can get this value explicitly. From the [Conjugate Gradient documentation of Scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.cg.html), it is mentioned that the output of the function comes with the solution and with an integer `info`, where you can only know the number of iteration when the convergence to tolerance was not achieved:

> `0` : successful exit
>
> `>0` : convergence to tolerance not achieved, number of iterations
>
> `<0` : illegal input or breakdown

A solution would be to increase the tolerance (or max number of iteration) until the convergence is reached and the function returns 0 for the `info` variable.